# Bash script for encoding conversion

Tags: bash

I'd like to convert all my work on a LaTeX book from ISO8859-1 to UTF-8.

I found a script that I would like to adapt. So here's what I wrote :

```
# start encoding
encodeFrom='ISO-8859-1'
# target encoding
encodeTo='UTF-8'
# finding files whose extensions correspond to the given parameter
for filename in ` find . -type f -name *.{$1}`
do    
    echo $filename
    # saving source file
    mv $filename $filename.save
    # convert file
    iconv -f $encodeFrom -t $encodeTo $filename.save -o $filename
    # check that file is in unix mode
    dos2unix $filename
done
```

Problem is : the 'find' command doesn't work : testing it with "set -v", I get :

```
find . -type f -name *.{$1}
```

What did I do wrong ? I tried to find my way threw a bash book (as a matter of fact, two :-), but couldn't find a solution.

Even trying for just tex files conversions :

```
for filename in ` find . -type f -name *.tex`
```

I get :

```
find: les chemins doivent précéder l'expression : arithmetique.tex
```

Comment: When you have an answer that solves your question -- click the accept answer, but don't update the title or the text with `[solved]`

Answer (score 2):

> See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), why you should *NOT* parse output of `find` or `ls` in a for loop.

Use a proper process-substitution syntax with a while-loop and *ALWAYS* double-quote your variables.

```
while IFS= read -r filename
do
    echo "$filename"
    mv "$filename" "${filename}".save
    iconv -f "$encodeFrom" -t "$encodeTo" "${filename}".save -o "$filename"
    dos2unix "$filename"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.{$1}")
```

As  suggests below recommend using `-print0` option in `find` in case if your filenames have a new line character, whitespace or any other special characters,

```
-print0
       True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character 
       (instead of the  newline  character  that  -print  uses). This allows  file  names  
       that contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by 
       programs that process the find output.
```

Using it in `find`

```
while IFS= read -r -d'' filename
do
    echo "$filename"
    mv "$filename" "${filename}".save
    iconv -f "$encodeFrom" -t "$encodeTo" "${filename}".save -o "$filename"
    dos2unix "$filename"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.{$1}" -print0)
```

Using it appends the `\0` between filenames and the read separates filenames with the same character, ensures your `find` results are intact.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening, @inian :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS: See [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: This suffers from the same problem that parsing `ls` does: file names with newlines in them.

Comment: @chepner: Updated with the `-print0` option.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer : just "protect" the argument '*.$1' like this : "*.$1".

All I had to do was ask :-)

\bye

Comment: Can you see if my answer helped?

Comment: OK. Sorry for forgetting to accept correctly your answer :-(

Comment: While double quotes is needed around $1 then it is not sufficient to solve the issues in the script